# What is the C++ datatype that corresponds to AS3 Number (Integral)

Tags: c++, actionscript-3

So what would be the datatype I am looking at. I know AS3 Number is 64 bit but it is double precision. I am converting code to C++ and since in AS3 it is valid to do this:

```
var i:Number = 123;
i >> 3; // Yeah shift right a double precision datatype
```

So in C++ I need now a datatype that is in the integral range of the Number type in AS3 (which is double precision). Please note I am converting and encode/decode functions that were previously used with the AS3 code so I must have the same result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say double precision but then you say Integral in the title. Which is it? Integral types don't have precision, they just have a size and whether or not it's signed.

Comment: Sorry I think I am confusing.. Will try to redefine a little.

Comment: The point is that in AS3 you can do bitwise operations on Number datatype (which is double precision type). However you cannot do the same one in C++. So I need to find a datatype in C++ on which I can perform bitwise operations (so it must be Integral as far as I know) and still have the same range as Number has (omiting the stuff after the coma i guess). So what is the maximum Integral value a Number can hold

Comment: What does AS3 even do when you apply bitwise operations on a floating-point number?

Comment: @cdhowie: That was going to be my question. I assume they apply them only to the mantissa; that's the only thing that even begins to make sense.

Comment: Yes I think only on the mantissa. Now what I do is I declare the variables in C++ as double and use the following macro #define D2I(X) ((__int64)(X)) when I have a problem with the double. I think this will work.

Comment: @user1715070: I don't think that will do what you want; it's definitely going to be incapable of storing the entire range possible on a double.

Comment: I sense some brain-curdling macros will be the solution to this unfortunate problem. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AS3 shift operator converts the expression being shifted and the shift amount to 32-bit integers. In C++, you emulate this behavior by casting a double data type to an int and shifting:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    double i(91.5);
    int v(static_cast<int>(i) >> 3);
    std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl; // outputs "v = 11"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The macro I currently try to implement is #define D2I(X) ((__int64)(X)). Basically i need to change it to #define D2I(X) ((__int32)(X))

Comment: Yes, your macro should suffice. I would give preference to C++-style casts and inline functions rather than macros: inline __int32 d2i(const double& v) { return static_cast<__int32>(v); }

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in AS3 Number is a double precision number, so in C++ it'll be `double` type. But, bit shifts in AS3 are done via implicit conversion. You should check if the result is actually an int, or a double, and if int, you do

```
i=floor(i/8.0);
```

and if double, you drop floor() call.

In short, you have to explicitly rewrite operations that are done on ints instead of doubles. But, you can do like `(int)i` when an operation requires an int, and i is double.